# How can we calculate transverse and longitudinal optical phonon frequencies

Tags: vasp, phonopy, dielectric-constants

Could you please help me to calculate the "transverse and longitudinal optical phonon frequencies" from phonopy+vasp output files?[image]
These parameters will help me to calculate the high-frequency dielectric constant as shown in the Eq. 1.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but since it has been more than 6 months, is there any update you can provide us? Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question? Please let us know!